# Do mobs get stronger the further you're away from your spawn point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Do mobs literally get stronger in Minecraft? I'm reading a book and it said that mobs get stronger the further you are away from spawn. For instance, mobs would spawn with better armor and witches are more common.

Is this true? And if so, how does that even work?

Comment: What book is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge no. Mobs themselves are not given any additional powers and I do not believe it becomes more likely for them to be spawned with better gear or for certain mobs to spawn more frequently.

The Minecraft wiki has [all the information about mob spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Spawn_Cycle) you could want.

There is a [regional difficulty mechanic](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Regional_difficulty) such that the longer players spend in chunks, the higher the regional difficulty is, although there is a cap to this difficulty and it doesn't dramatically affect your experience vs world difficulty.

This would imply the opposite of what you're suggesting. Rather than traveling increasing difficulty, staying in place is what increases it.

Comment: The only way one could read the asker's book to match reality is that piglin brutes, wither skeletons and hoglins are more brutal than most overworld mobs, and the Ender Dragon is even more powerful.